# AWK recursive tree structure

Tags: bash, awk, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to parse a file that contains lines in a hierarchical structure. For example the file:

```
a b c
a b d
a B C
A B C
```

indicates that `a` contains `b` and `B`, that `b` contains `c` and `d`, that `B` contains `C`. `A` contains a different `B` which contains its own `C`.

This is much like a list of files.

I want to format this in a hierarchical bracketed way like:

```
a {
    b {
        c
        d
    }
    B {
        C
    }
}
A {
    B {
        C
    }
}
```

I couldn't come up with a decent way to do this. I thought that AWK would be my best bet, but came up short with how to actually implement it.

#### Context

My input is actually a list of files. I can of course separate the fields by spaces if needed, or keep them with `/`. The files are unordered and generated from a code-base during compile-time via inspection. My desired output is going to be a graphviz DOT file containing each file in its own subgraph.

Thus for the input:

```
a/b/c
a/b/d
a/B/C
A/B/C
```

the output would be

```
digraph {
  subgraph cluster_a {
    label = a
    subgraph cluster_b {
        label = b
        node_1 [label=c]
        node_2 [label=d]
    }
    subgraph cluster_B {
        label = B
        node_3 [label=C]
    }
  }
  subgraph cluster_A {
      label = A
      subgraph cluster_B {
          label = B
          node_4 [label=C]
      }
  }
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Does anybody know how I could get this processing done? I'm open to other tools as well, not just AWK.

NOTE: Depth is not fixed, though I could pre-compute the maximum depth if necessary. Not all leaves will be at the same depth either.

Comment: what would it look like if you have `a/b/c` and `a/b/d`? i.e. 2 leaf nodes in a subcluster?

Comment: I just edited the example to show.

Comment: Can there be more than 3 levels like `a b d x` or `a b d p q r` ?

Comment: Added a NOTE at the end with further clarification, but yes, there can be more than 3 levels and there can be leaves at any level.

Comment: You mentioned input is unordered. Does it mean `a b d p q r` record can come after `w x y z` also whereas `a b c` can be at top of file?

Comment: yep, you could create a decent 'test datum' by taking any directory and running `find . -type f | shuf` (minus the fact that in my specific instance all paths are absolute)

Comment: If you wan't to do it with awk, data **shoul'd** be sorted. Else you better use an other scripting language like python which has already tree data structure.

Comment: Like I said, I'd be open to a relatively short and quick solution in another language. I'm also open to adding to the pipeline. If a simple `sort | awk ...` makes life easier, then that's fine by me!

Comment: Where is your code? As nicely as this problem is presented, if your question is tagged `awk`, I would hope to see some awk code in your question.

Comment: I didn't save my initial attempted code as I realized while typing it out that it would be tedious (creating associative arrays of directories). Nonetheless, that is the solution I ended up accepting from @cody, only in python. A 'port' of that python solution to a clean `awk` solution would steal the 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm open to other tools as well, not just AWK.

I offer this Python solution:

```
import sys

INDENT = '  '
NODE_COUNT = 1


def build(node, l):
    x = l[0]
    if x not in node:
        node[x] = {}

    if len(l) > 1:
        build(node[x], l[1:])


def indent(s, depth):
    print('%s%s' % (INDENT * depth, s))


def print_node(label, value, depth):

    if len(value.keys()) > 0:
        indent('subgraph cluster_%s {' % label, depth)
        indent('  label = %s' % label, depth)
        for child in value:
            print_node(child, value[child], depth+1)
        indent('}', depth)
    else:
        global NODE_COUNT
        indent('node_%d [label=%s]' % (NODE_COUNT, label), depth)
        NODE_COUNT += 1


def main():

    d = {}

    for line in sys.stdin:
        build(d, [x.strip() for x in line.split()])

    print('digraph {')
    for k in d.keys():
        print_node(k, d[k], 1)
    print('}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
$ cat rels.txt
a b c
a b d
a B C
A B C

$ cat rels.txt | python3 make_rels.py
digraph {
  subgraph cluster_a {
    label = a
    subgraph cluster_b {
      label = b
      node_1 [label=c]
      node_2 [label=d]
    }
    subgraph cluster_B {
      label = B
      node_3 [label=C]
    }
  }
  subgraph cluster_A {
    label = A
    subgraph cluster_B {
      label = B
      node_4 [label=C]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works with modification for my purposes. It's not as clean as I was hoping, but gets the job done :)

Answer (score 2):

If the depth is fixed at 3 levels

```
gawk -F/ '
    {f[$1][$2][$3] = 1}
    END {
        n = 0
        print "digraph {"
        for (a in f) {
            print "  subgraph cluster_" a " {"
            print "    label = " a
            for (b in f[a]) {
                print "    subgraph cluster_" b " {"
                print "      label = " b
                for (c in f[a][b]) {
                    printf "      node_%d [label=%s]\n", ++n, c
                }
                print "    }"
            }
            print "  }"
        }
        print "}"
    }
' file
```

```
digraph {
  subgraph cluster_A {
    label = A
    subgraph cluster_B {
      label = B
      node_1 [label=C]
    }
  }
  subgraph cluster_a {
    label = a
    subgraph cluster_B {
      label = B
      node_2 [label=C]
    }
    subgraph cluster_b {
      label = b
      node_3 [label=c]
      node_4 [label=d]
    }
  }
}
```

If the depth is arbitrary, things get complicated.

Comment: Unfortunately depth is arbitrary, so things are complicated. Good solution for fixed depth though!